# Catch chef exception

Tags: ruby, exception, vagrant, chef-infra

I have receipt for installing package

```
package 'some_package' do
    ignore_fail true
end
```

And I want to know if installing failed and try for example install something else.

So my question is: how to proceed exceptions in chef receipt.

Comment: use a rescue block and handle the exception

Comment: @IsabelHM what do you mean ? a begin/rescue block won't catch at converge time (or I absolutely did forget it). Do you mean within a ruby_block ?

Comment: catch chef exception while installing a package? If the flag to ignore failure is not set to true, it will catch the exception using the rescue block. Unless I misunderstood the original question, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. Chef resources don't have output values of any kind, they are self-contained convergent promises. You would have to fall back to implementing the install operations yourself, either in a bash script or in Ruby using the `shell_out` helpers.

The Right Way™ to use Chef would be to be prescriptive about what each machine should have installed by checking either something in the node data or something about the machine. What is it that would make the install fail? Look for that and use `only_if`/`not_if` as needed.